# My Neural Network Model for predicting soccer outcomes doesn't increase to more than 50%

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a model to predict soccer outcomes, I've tried a lot of different models, such as Neural Network in Matlab, Deep Networks using keras in Python and LSTM. My accuracy doesn't increase more than 50%

I have collected 24000 matches from 13 different leagues that have the same aspect (win by points). My data is consisted by:

```
                The week of the league that is ocurring that match
                Ratings of all the 22 titular players
                Goals Average 
                Goals Against Average
                Shots_H, Shots_A,
                ShotsOnTarget_H, ShotsOnTarget_A,
                PassSuccess_H, PassSuccess_A,
                AerialDuelSuccess_H, AerialDuelSuccess_A,
                DribblesWon_H, DribblesWon_A,
                Tackles_H, Tackles_A,
                Posesion_H, Posesion_A,
                Rating_H, Rating_A,
                DribbleSucces_H, DribbleSucces_A,
                TacklesSucces_H, TacklesSucces_A,
                Interceptions_H, Interceptions_A,
                Dispossesse_H, Dispossesse_A,
                Corners_H, Corners_A,
```

I have made a mean weighted average of the last 5 matches from all that data to use as inputs in a neural network model playing home, and playing away. So, if a home team are going to play a match, the data will be the mean weighted average from the last 5 matches playing in the home field (the last one have more weight than the second last one, and so on). The output is one hot encoded: (1 0 0) for win home, (0 1 0) draw...

I've tried several models, and now I'm trying Keras Dense model.

I am scaling the input data using:

```py
sc = StandardScaler()
entrada_training = sc.fit_transform(entrada_training)
entrada_validation  = sc.transform (entrada_validation)
entrada_teste  = sc.transform (entrada_teste)
```

and the model is:

```py
drop=0.3
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(40, input_shape=(57,), activation='relu'))
#model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(drop))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(drop))
#model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(drop))
#model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))


adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)

mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('.mdl_wts.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.0001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(entrada_training, saida_training,
                   batch_size=28,
                   epochs=100,
                   verbose=2,
                   callbacks=[mcp_save, reduce_lr],
                  # class_weight=d_class_weights,
                   validation_data=(entrada_validation, saida_validation))
```

The maximum result i could achieve was 50% accuracy on test set, but with the confusion matrix i could see that the model was not predicting any draws, so I add a weight to classes:

```py
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
y_integers = np.argmax(saida_training, axis=1)
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_integers), y_integers)
d_class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
```

And achieved 46% of accuracy but with a better confusion matrix.

I really don't know what to do, I've tried a lot of different models, activation functions, and methods but the accuracy doesn't seem to change too much.

Edit: I did the correlation matrix and saw that the maximum correlation with the result is no higher than 0.2. And I saw that 6 variables are correlated with each other with 0.87 correlation coeficient. I have deleted the variables with correlation less than 0.05 with the result. From 57 variables, I have now 44, and still got the same accuracy of 45%.

Comment: Any chance you can make the dataset available for people to play with it ? It seems like a fun problem. Did you look at a correlation matrix between the features of your model and the outcomes that you are trying to predict ? often ```np.corrcoef``` or ```pandas.DataFrame.corr()``` are useful to determine what kind of correlation the features have. I would first try to examine the data by plotting correlations.

Comment: BTW: keep in mind that there are games of luck such as https://www.jogossantacasa.pt/web/JogarTotobola/ which have the underlying assumption that the outcome of predicting win, tie, loss is random.  That assumption is probably rooted in good statistical analysis. It is likely that those people know what they are doing and that 50% (coin toss) is the best you can do.

Comment: maybe it is impossible to predict soccer outcome...

Comment: It seems to be related to your data instead of your model.

Comment: It is not that easy to build a good model for predicting football game results, one of the main reasons is insufficient data (at least for neural models). There is no simple way to augment the data to proper sizes. Even a 53% of accuracy would be considered an amazing result for that kind of models.

Comment: from your data, looks like something from Opta, you wont get higher because you need to factor in team form, player form, missing players,  formation, coach strategy (formations and familiarity of players), archetype (lower tier team vs higher tier team plays differently - more defensive)